# Micronaut Launch x Gradle issue

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I'm trying to follow the Micronaut gRPC guide by creating an application with the following settings:

[image]

After importing the app, I'm getting the following error:

```
% ./gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'genz'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2.
     Required by:
         project : > io.micronaut.application:io.micronaut.application.gradle.plugin:4.0.2
      > No matching variant of io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.2.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.micronaut.gradle:micronaut-gradle-plugin:4.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.2.1')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 929ms
```

Comment: Looks like you re running Gradle with Java 11...

Comment: @SaschaFrinken what do you suggest that I try instead?

Comment: Micronaut 4 requires Java 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to switch to Java 17:

```
% sdk use java 17.0.8-zulu
```